# Cómo usar un array y subir archivos usando ajax y PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

Hola buenas tardes a todos tengo un problemita cuando intento enviar imagen o archivo por ajax, lo que pasa estoy usando una librería typeahead y tagmanager para agregar tags con consulta a BD y lo almaceno en un array para luego procesarlas en donde lo hice bien pero cuando agrego new FormData(this); para subir archivos en el post no me envía nada.

Eso usando en mis otros formularios sin eso de tags funciona bien pero el array que esta almacenado en js no funciona con subir archivos al mismo tiempo array y subir archivo.

Cuando lo hago sin file normal me proceso pero con el file me da problema espero su ayuda.

Imagen 1 cuando no tiene el file normal se envía al post.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen 2 cuando agrego el file en el JS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var miArray = [];
        v = 0;
        function quitararea(v) {
            valor = v - 1;
            miArray.splice(valor, 1);
            console.log(miArray);
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var tags = $(".tm-input").tagsManager();
            jQuery(".typeahead").typeahead({
                source: function(query, process) {
                    return $.get('consulta_sql.php', {
                        query: query
                    }, function(data) {
                        data = $.parseJSON(data);
                        return process(data);
                    });
                },
                afterSelect: function(item) {
                    var divisiones = item.split(" - ");
                    agregar = [divisiones[0], divisiones[1]];

                    for (var i = 0; i < miArray.length; i++) {
                        if (miArray[i][0] == divisiones[0]) {
                            alert("Ya se encuentra agregada la área!");                          
                            $('#area').val('');
                            return miArray;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    tags.tagsManager("pushTag", divisiones[1]);
                    $('#area').val('');
                    miArray.push(agregar);
                    console.log(miArray);
                    return miArray;
                }
            });
        });
        $("#enviar").submit(function(event) {

            arraypasar = JSON.stringify(miArray);
            var datos = $(this).serialize();
            var arrayparametros = {arraypasar: arraypasar,datos: datos};
          /*  var data = new FormData(this); */
            $.ajax({
               
                type: 'post',
                cache: false,
                url: "post.php",
                data: arrayparametros,
                /* data: data,               
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,  */
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#resultado").html(data);
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
```

PHP

```
$data = json_decode($_REQUEST['arraypasar']);


/* $archivo = $_FILES["archivo_add"]['name']; */

parse_str($_REQUEST['datos'], $valores);

/* echo $archivo; */

echo "<br>";
echo $valores['area2'];

echo "<br><br>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data); 
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Sugerencia: evita la mayúscula sostenida. Lo mismo: es mejor un título que rdescriba el problema y no una colección de keywords que no dicen cuál es tu problema con el código.

Comment: Lo tomare en cuenta gracias por la corrección

Comment: ¿usas enctype="multipart/form-data"? si no lo usas cuando pasas el formulario a data no se toman los archivos

Comment: Si uso <form name="enviar" id="enviar" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Cuando quito el array almacenado ahi si funciona normal pero cuando agrego JSON.stringify(miArray); no funciona habrá forma de hacerlo en uno solo o tal vez tendría que separarlos en otra función solo para subir archivos

Comment: Ya lo solucione abajo dejé mi idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola bueno lo resolví de la manera siguiente tuve que separar el array de tags del submit llamando dentro del post.php a la función para que procese el array creado. No quería separarlo pero esa idea se me ocurrió pensaba hacerlo en uno solo.

Bueno ahí les dejo mi código como lo resolví para quienes usan tags.

Saludos.

```
//AQUI AGREGA LOS TAGS Y LO ALMACENO EN UN ARRAY
    var miArray = [];
        v = 0;

        function quitararea(v) {
            valor = v - 1;
            miArray.splice(valor, 1);
            console.log(miArray);
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var tags = $(".tm-input").tagsManager();
            jQuery(".typeahead").typeahead({
                source: function(query, process) {
                    return $.get('consulta_sql.php', {
                        query: query
                    }, function(data) {
                        data = $.parseJSON(data);
                        return process(data);
                    });
                },
                afterSelect: function(item) {
                    var divisiones = item.split(" - ");
                    agregar = [divisiones[0], divisiones[1]];

                    for (var i = 0; i < miArray.length; i++) {
                        if (miArray[i][0] == divisiones[0]) {
                            alert("Ya se encuentra agregada la área!");
                            $('#area').val('');
                            return miArray;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    tags.tagsManager("pushTag", divisiones[1]);
                    $('#area').val('');
                    miArray.push(agregar);
                    console.log(miArray);                       
                    return miArray;
                }
            });
        });

//SUBMIT DEL FOMULARIO
        $("#enviar").submit(function(event) {
            var parametros = $(this).serialize();
            var data = new FormData(this);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: "post.php",
                data: parametros,
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(datos) {           
                    $("#resultado").html(datos);
                   

                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });

//FUNCION QUE HACE RECOGER EL ARRAY CREADO
        function copia(codigo) {
            arraypasar = JSON.stringify(miArray);
            var doc = $("#area2").val();
            var folios = $("#area3").val();
            var arrayparametros = {
                arraypasar: arraypasar,
                codigo: codigo,
                doc: doc,
                folios: folios
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: "post2.php",
                data: arrayparametros,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#resultado2").html(data);
                  
                }
            });
        };
```